# Unknown character/symbol/sign in a Taiwanese manhua - Resolved, thank you

Tags: traditional-characters, taiwanese, onomatopoeia

Please, help me identify the meaning/purpose/origins of this symbol/sign/character?

[image]

[image]

I suppose it might be used to describe emotions (like irritation or surprise?) or for onomatopoeia. However, I have no idea where to find any info on what it really means.

I could not find anything in Traditional Chinese vocabs and some Japanese sources. I found similar-looking letter for Hindi - does not help though :(

Any help from people who know what is going on or can advise where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: Zhuyin [ㄛ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%84%9B)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

It is the symbol "ㄛ" in Zhuyin, which may represent the word "哦" or "喔".

Comment: Thank you so-so much !

Comment: You are welcome.